# Prevent View from invalidation whole root View

Tags: android

hope you having a nice day , there is a problem that im stuck with , due to my need to a marquee TextView but for RTL languages , since the normal android marquee couldnt do so , i did put a textview into a HorizontalScrollView

```
  <HorizontalScrollView 
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:id="@+id/hs"
                      android:scrollbars="none"
                      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                      >

                  <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/moving_tv"
    android:text="                                                                        Your SubTitle ...                                                                                         "
    android:singleLine="true" 
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:textColor="@color/color_white"
    android:background="@color/color_black"
    android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      />

    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

and i am scolling it in a Timer() like this :

```
  task = new TimerTask() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        if(hs.getScrollX() == 0){

                            hs.scrollTo((hs.getChildAt(0).getMeasuredWidth()- windowSize),0);
                            return;
                        }

                        hs.smoothScrollBy(-1,0);




                    }
                };



    }

    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 50);
```

the problem is , whenever the task runs , and so the view scrolls it calls InvalidateChildInParent() on himself and all Layouts in its ViewGroup to the root, so my whole view is refreshing and calling DispatchDraw() ,Draw() and OnDraw() for like 20 times in a second !!! the battery , and it appears a poison for performance and the battery . is there any way to prevent the ScrollView refresh its Parents ? Thanks alot

Comment: It may be easier to use library https://github.com/ened/Android-MarqueeView

Comment: thanks mate , hate you tested it ? would it help in my case?

Comment: yes, it will help. You can clone it and run the sample project and see for yourself

Comment: well i did read the code , seems it uses an animation , and animations invalidate the parent too , so its the same , while my own implemention can be scrolled by hand